# What is the ratio of the areas of regions defined by $\log_{10}(1+x^2+y^2)\leq1+\log_{10}(x+y)$ and $\log_{10}(2+x^2+y^2)\leq2+\log_{10}(x+y)$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let 
$$S_{1} = \{(x, y)| \log_{10}(1 + x^2 + y^2) \leq 1 + \log_{10}(x + y)\}$$
$$S_{2} = \{(x, y)| \log_{10}(2 + x^2 + y^2) \leq 2 + \log_{10}(x + y)\}$$
What is the ratio of the area of $S_{2}$ to the area of $S_{1}$?

Comment: You've been here long enough to know that the community prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker know about the problem. Please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3572732/edit) to describe what you tried, where you got stuck, and/or other details. This will help answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining what you already know or talking over your head.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You can express the areas as $$S_1: 1+x^2+y^2\le 10x+10y\\S_2: 2+x^2+y^2\le 100x+100y$$Note that we implicitly have $x+y>0$